# CSS: where does this margin come from?

Tags: html, css

Here's my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gregseth/548S2/

Why is there a white space between the elements? And how can I get rid of it?

In addition why are the dimensions of the `<img>` not taken into account on jsfiddle, when it is on a 'normal' HTML page (Firefox)?

Comment: Hint: http://jsfiddle.net/548S2/1/

Comment: display:inline-block is causing problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the

```
nav a { display:inline-block; }
```

If you'd change this to:

```
nav a {    
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

the margins are gone.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/548S2/3/

Comment: In this simplified case, a float will work fine but it may be more complex when you try this on a full website. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of HTML rendering a space when block items have a space or line break between them. You can either float the items to the left:

http://jsfiddle.net/548S2/4/

or remove the line breaks between the elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/548S2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just apply **float:left** to the "nav a" in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

It's the spaces (the line breaks) between the `<a>` elements in your html. This happens on all `inline` or `inline-block` elements.

**OPTION 1:**
Use `margin-right:-4px;` on the `<a>` tags.

**OPTION 2:**
Remove the spaces between the `<a>` tags.

**OPTION 3:**
Change the `<a>` tags to `display:block; float:left` as described in other answers. In this case, you need to fix the height of the container element (`<nav>` in your case), or use a `clear:left` on the next element to prevent the floats overlapping it. Sometimes it's useful to avoid this floating approach and use one of the other options.